# What is difference in performance of following 2 queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the difference in performance of following 2 queries in SQL Server 2008

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT A.Id,A.Name,B.Class,B.Std,C.Result,D.Grade 
FROM Student A
INNER JOIN Classes B ON B.ID = A.ID
INNER JOIN Results C ON C.ID = A.ID
INNER JOIN Grades D ON D.Name = A.Name
WHERE A.Name='Test' AND A.ID=3
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT A.Id,A.Name,B.Class,B.Std,C.Result,D.Grade 
FROM Student A 
INNER JOIN Classes B ON B.ID = A.ID AND A.Name='Test' AND A.ID=3
INNER JOIN Results C ON C.ID = A.ID
INNER JOIN Grades D ON D.Name = A.Name
```

Is there any best way to achieve the best perofermance in the above 2 queries

Comment: Are you sure this join is right? `INNER JOIN Grades D ON D.Name = A.Name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a 100% guarantee that they execute the same, with the same plan.

The only time it does matter when splitting AND/WHERE clauses in an INNER JOIN is when options like FORCE ORDER is used.

---

For great performance at the expense of writes, create these indexes:

```
A (id, name)
B (id) includes (class, std)
C (id) includes (result)
D (name) includes (grade)
```

However, it still depends on your distribution of data and selectivity of indexes as to whether they will actually be used.  e.g. if your Grade table contains only 5 entries A,B,C,D,E, then no index will be used, it will simply scan and buffer the table in memory.

Comment: Dont you think filtering the data with where condition after all joins and filtering the data before join conditions makes the difference. In this case if you see [[WHERE A.Name='Test' AND A.ID=3 ]] is at the end after all joins in Query1 where as in Query2 it is not like that, there we are filtering the data before JOIN conditions..

Comment: @vinni - For inner joins, they mean the same thing. You can ask SQL Server to do something, but cannot control exactly how it will do it. It can use the WHERE condition as part of the join and can use the join as a filter - there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the execution plans of each, you'll find they're in all likelihood going to have identical execution plans.

The way to best improve performance for these kinds of queries is to make sure that you've got the proper indexes set up.  All of your `ID` columns should have indexes on them, and if `Grades` is a largeish table, consider putting an index on `Name` for both it and `Student`

Comment: Dont you think filtering the data with where condition after all joins and filtering the data before join conditions makes the difference. In this case if you see [[WHERE A.Name='Test' AND A.ID=3 ]] is at the end after all joins in Query1 where as in Query2 it is not like that, there we are filtering the data before JOIN conditions.. – Vinni 49 secs ago